# break and next functions in R on a single word using strsplit() function

Tags: r, break, strsplit

I am trying to use break and next in for loop, my code is as below:

```
for(i in strsplit('chapter', '')){
  if(i == 'p'){
    break
  }
  print(i)
}
```

Expected output:

```
c
h
a

for(i in strsplit('chapter', '')){
  if(i == 'p'){
    next
  }
  print(i)
}
```

Expected Output:

```
c
h
a
t
e
r
```

But my output for both of above loops is:

```
[1] "c" "h" "a" "p" "t" "e" "r"
Warning message:
In if (i == "p") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>
```

Also I don't understand the Warning message, why I am getting that.
I tried another numeric example:

```
x <- c(1,5,2,6,8,5,9,1)
for (val in x) {
  if (val == 5){
    next
  }
  print(val)
}
```

Output is:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 1
>
```

Here although number 5 is there in two places in the vector, the output doesn't show  the warning "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the output of `strsplit`

```
strsplit('chapter', '')

#[[1]]
#[1] "c" "h" "a" "p" "t" "e" "r"
```

It is a list of length 1 and that list has individual elements. So when you iterate over it in a `for` loop you are just iterating over 1st list element. What you needed is to select the first list element and then iterate over each individual elements.

```
strsplit('chapter', '')[[1]]
#[1] "c" "h" "a" "p" "t" "e" "r"
```

You will get your required output if you do

```
for(i in strsplit('chapter', '')[[1]]){
   if(i == 'p'){
      break
   }
   print(i)
}

#[1] "c"
#[1] "h"
#[1] "a"

for(i in strsplit('chapter', '')[[1]]){
  if(i == 'p'){
     next
   }
  print(i)
}

#[1] "c"
#[1] "h"
#[1] "a"
#[1] "t"
#[1] "e"
#[1] "r"
```